# How to use Intune iOS SDK with MSAL, instead of ADAL?

Tags: ios, azure-ad-msal, intune

How to use Intune SDK with MSAL, instead of ADAL? In the official documentation only examples of ADAL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-ios, but I need to use Intune with new auth library MSAL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured out, unfortunately, it's not yet supported because Intune SDK itself would need to do updates. Refer this issue on Github: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/245